# How do I use nested implementations of interfaces in Castle Windsor?

Tags: nested, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

Suppose I have an interface for fetching data, and an implementation of it:

```
interface IResourceProvider
{
  string Get( Uri uri );
}

class HttpResourceProvider : IResourceProvider
{
  public string Get( Uri uri )
  {
    // Download via HTTP.
  }
}
```

I can register this in Castle Windsor as follows:

```
container.Register
  ( Component.For<IResourceProvider>().ImplementedBy<HttpResourceProvider>()
  );
```

(Which is all fine).

If I then decided I wanted a caching implementation as follows:

```
class CachingResourceProvider : IResourceProvider
{
  public CachingResourceProvider( IResourceProvider resourceProvider )
  {
    _resourceProvider = resourceProvider;
  }

  public string Get( Uri uri )
  {
    // Return from cache if it exists.
    // Otherwise use _resourceProvider and add to cache.
  }

  private readonly IResourceProvider _resourceProvider;
}
```

**How would I register these nested dependencies?** i.e., I want to say an `IResourceProvider` is implemented by a `CachingResourceProvider`, except where in the constructor, where it's a `HttpResourceProvider`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just register `CachingResourceProvider` before `HttpResourceProvider` - e.g.

```
container.Register(Component
    .For<IResourceProvider>()
    .ImplementedBy<CachingResourceProvider>());
container.Register(Component
    .For<IResourceProvider>()
    .ImplementedBy<HttpResourceProvider>());
```

BTW - this is know as the [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

This is known as the Decorator Pattern...

See this link as an example:  http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2010/01/10-advanced-windsor-tricks-4-how-to.html